# Does computer rounds the numbers in an operation first or round the result?

Tags: math, floating-point, ieee-754

For instance, in opreation 9.4 - 9.0 - 0.4: Does computer first rounds the each number and store or does it make the computation with the help of some extra bits (this example is in double precision format) and then rounds the result? These are the stored values, but wasn't sure how to make this operation by hand to check if it rounds each number first or not.

binary( 9.4) = 0 10000000010 0010110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101

binary(-9.0) = 1 10000000010 0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

binary(-0.4) = 1 01111111101 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010

binary(9.4 - 9.0 - 0.4) = 0 01111001100 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: There is no way to represent exactly 9.4 with IEEE754 double precision. Also, as far as I know, there is no operation defined which does two additions/subtractions at the same time. So could you be more specific what operations in what order you assume to happen?

Comment: Some compilers for some languages will use decimal instead of binary, thereby making the question moot.  The result will be exactly zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the computer will convert the numerals in `9.4 - 9.0 - 0.4` to numbers in an internal form, and then it will perform the arithmetic operations. These conversions generally round their results.

Consider the text in source code `9.4 - 9.0 - 0.4`. Nothing in there is a number. That text is a string composed of characters. It contains the characters “9”, ”.”, “4”, “ ”, “-”, and so on. Generally, a computer converts this text to other forms for processing. You could write software that works with numbers in a text format, but this is rare. Generally, when we are using a programming language, either compiled or interpreted, the numerals in this text will be converted to some internal form. (A “numeral” is a sequence of symbols representing a number. So “9.4” is a numeral representing 9.4.)

IEEE-754 binary64 is a very common floating-point format. In this format, each representable number is expressed in units of some power of two.  For example, the numbers .125, .250, .375, and .500 are also representable because they are multiples of 1/8, which is 2<sup>−3</sup>. However, 9.4 is not a multiple of any power of two, so it cannot be represented in IEEE-754 binary64.

When `9.4` is converted to binary64, the nearest representable value is 9.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625. (This is a multiple of 2<sup>−50</sup>, which is the power of two used when representing numbers near 9.4, specifically numbers from 8 [inclusive] to 16 [exclusive].)

9 is representable in binary64, so `9` is converted to 9.

0.4 is not representable in binary64. When `0.4` is converted to binary64, the nearest representable value is 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625. This is a multiple of 2<sup>−54</sup>, which is the power of two used for numbers from ¼ to ½.

In `9.4 - 9.0 - 0.4`, the result of the first subtraction is 0.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625. This is exactly representable, so there is no rounding at this point. Then, when `0.4` is subtracted, after it has been converted to the value above, the result is 0.00000000000000033306690738754696212708950042724609375. This is also exactly representable, so there is again no rounding at this point.

The above describes what happens if binary64 is used throughout. Many programming languages, or specific implementations of them, use binary64. Some may use other formats. Some languages permit implementations to use a mix of formats—they may use a wider format than binary64 for doing calculations and convert to binary64 for the final result. This can cause you to see different results than the above.

So the answer to your question is that, with floating-point arithmetic, **each** operation produces a result that is equal to the number you would get by computing the exact real-number result and then rounding that real-number results to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format. (Rounding is most often done by rounding to the nearest representable value, with ties resolved by one of several methods, but other rounding choices are possible, such as rounding down.)

The operations generally do not round their operands. (There are exceptions, such as that some processors may convert subnormal inputs to zero.) However, those operands must be produced first, such as by converting source text to a representable number. Those conversions are separate operations from the subtraction or other operations that follow.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Some programs or some machines may use extra precision for intermediate results. This depends on lots of factors: the hardware available, what programming language you're using, what compiler you're using, what options you passed in to the compiler, etc. For example programs compiled for Intel CPU may sometimes use 80-bit precision for intermediate results, if they are compiled to use [x87 instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87).

For the rest of the answer I'll assume all operations are done in 64 bit "double precision" floating point numbers.

Each number is rounded first, and the results are rounded too. For example 9.4 cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point number, so `9.4` in a program is *rounded to the closest floating point number*. With 64-bit precision floats, the exact mathematical value of that number is:

```
9.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625
```

So 9.4 is "rounded" to 9.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625.

Similarly, 0.4 cannot be represented exactly. It is "rounded" to:

```
0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
```

The results of a computation may need to be rounded as well. Multiplication of two N-digit numbers produces a number with 2N digits. If you can only store N digits, what's going to happen with the rest? They are rounded off.

Here you ask about subtraction. With numbers of different magnitudes, the result of subtraction must be rounded. In the particular case of `(9.4 - 9) - 0.4` all numbers have the same magnitude, so rounding of results is not happening, and the operations are mathematically exact:

Assuming all numbers are kept as 64 bit floats, the first subtraction computes:

```
9.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625 - 9.0 =
0.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625
```

The second subtraction computes:

```
  0.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625 
- 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
----------------------------------------------------------
  0.00000000000000033306690738754696212708950042724609375
```